# update excel cells with its uppercase text

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledb

i have the following problem with an excel file that i want to uppercase the values of its respective cells in C# with the next code:

```
DbProviderFactory factory =
                    DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");
                DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();

                string stringConnection = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1'",
                    excelPath);

                connection.ConnectionString = stringConnection;

                connection.Open();

                DbCommand updateExcel =
                    factory.CreateCommand();

                updateExcel.CommandText =
                    "UPDATE [sheet1$] SET lastname = UCASE(lastname), name = ucase(name)";

                updateExcel.Connection = connection;

                updateExcel.ExecuteNonQuery();

                conection.Close();
                connection.Dispose();
```

and it raise an oledbexception about parameters doesnt specified, anybody could help me?

Comment: You'll have to provide an excel sample.

Comment: You know, the error messages actually matter. How about you get the exact wording of the message and post it here verbatim. Also, which line raises the message. The details matter!!

Comment: the exception message is in spanish and i try to translate it as it doesnt specify values for some required parameters

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to an Excel 2007 or 2010 spreadsheet you will need the following connection string...

```
OleDbConnection xlconnection = new OleDbConnection();

xlconnection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FileName + @";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'"
```

Comment: thanks, but now its raise another error, maybe the sql statement it's wrong